# c++ list char acquisition issue, bad memory allocation?

Tags: c++, string, list, tail, head

this is my struct

```
struct list{
    char c;
    struct list * next;
};
```

and i have to put in this list a sequence of char, but when i try i get all the time segmentation fault

```
struct list * insert_list(){ 
//function for add a new string in the list
    struct list * tmp;
    string car;
    int i=0, len;
    cin >> car;
    len=car.size();
    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
        tmp=new list;
        tmp->c=car[i];
        tmp->next=NULL;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    return tmp;
}

struct list * head(struct list *top){
//this function adds the new string on ***TOP*** of the list
    struct list *tmp=NULL;
    tmp=insert_list();
    tmp->next=top;
    return tmp;
}

struct list * tail(struct list * top){
//this function adds the new string in the ***END*** of the list
    if (top==NULL){
        top=insert_list();
    }
    else{
        top->next=tail();
    }
    return top;
}
```

the problem i think is in the insert_list function, i tried also with a

```
while(tmp->c!='\n'){
    tmp=new list;
    cin >> tmp->c;   //also with cin.get
    tmp=tmp->next;
    tmp->next=NULL;
}
```

but i get all the time the same error.
how can i fix this?

Comment: Are you writing on C or C++?

Comment: There's some fundamental misunderstanding of what these functions do. `head()` should return the first element, `tail()` should return the rest of the list - neither of those functions should be creating new nodes ever.

Comment: it's in c++.
@Barry yeah i know that, but how can i add a sequence of char in head without creating a new node?

Comment: `tmp=tmp->next` - this doesn't do what you probably think it does. And what's the point of the `top` parameter to your `insert_list` function?

Comment: @wasd22 Can you please edit the question with you interpretation of what the different functions should do? It is unclear what it is you want them to do from the code. You are either quite far of in how you interpret the functions, or how you actually have written them.

Comment: @WhozCraig of course, the parameter of the insert_list function are useless.
what do you mean with the tmp=tmp->next doesn't do what i think it does?

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. I believe you think that statement somehow prepares the next iteration of the loop for the next allocation and will wire said allocation to the `next` of the prior-allocated node. And that simply isn't the case. From everything I see here I strongly urge you to review how pointers work in C++.

Comment: If you want a "list of cars", where each car is represented by a name, I suggest a different structure for list_entry...

Comment: You may be compiling it as C++, but it doesn't look very C++-like, does it?

Answer (score 1):

```
insert_list
```

Will always return null, so any calls to `head` will seg fault.
So will any other calls to insert_list that try to use the result.